# Routing a personal laptop through a company machine

Tags: networking, routing

Here is my situation.

At work I have to use an old, slow XP machine for development.  Suffice to say, it's painful to run Visual Studio on.  I have asked my dev manager about upgrading, but of course, no money (obviously a completely false economy, but what am I going to do?)

I do, however, have an awesome Macbook pro with Windows virtualized on VMWare as my personal machine.  I would love to be able to use this, but I can't join it to the domain (to access TFS, etc), and the support team do not seem interested in helping me out.

I'm wondering if it's possible for me to buy a cheap hub, connect both my Mac and my XP machine to it, and set up some kind of routing on the XP machine to forward requests from my Mac through the XP machine to the company network.  However, my networking skills are pretty basic, so not really sure if this is feasible. (Ignore any potential violations of company policy at this point.)

Anyone know if this is possible?

**Edit**: I should mention that I have local administrator access on the XP machine.

Answer (score 1):

XP has a feature called "Internet Connection Sharing" that can be used to do this.  It requires two network adapters to be installed within the system (one can be a wired NIC, the other a wireless NIC).  Depending on the amount of freedom you're given at this company you may be able to get a USB NIC and use that as the second NIC.

It won't give your Mac transparent access to things your XP machine has credentials for, but you could possibly set up shared folders on your XP's C: drive or other local drive and then access those through the Mac.

There's really no way to connect both your Mac and the XP machine to a hub and have the XP machine magically intercept what the Mac is trying to put through the hub and make it look like it is coming from itself.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts.  I think that ICS is disabled on this machine by group policy.  I go to Network Connections > Local Area Connection > Properties > Advanced tab, but only Windows Firewall Settings is available.  Could I achieve the same using a Network Bridge?